# What's the best way to store Logon User information for Web Application?

Tags: performance, scalability, authentication

I was once in a project of web application developed on ASP.NET. For each logon user, there is an object (let's call it **UserSessionObject** here) created and stored in RAM. For each HTTP request of given user, matching **UserSessoinObject** instance is used to visit user state information and connection to database. So, this **UserSessionObject** is pretty important.

This design brings several problems found later:

1) Since this **UserSessionObject** is cached in ASP.NET memory space, we have to config load balancer to be ***sticky connection***. That is, HTTP request in single session would always be sent to one web server behind. This limit scalability and maintainability.

2) This **UserSessionObject** is accessed in every HTTP request. To keep the consistency, there is a exclusive lock for the **UserSessionObject**. Only one HTTP request can be processed at any given time because it must to obtain the lock first. The performance and response time is affected.

Now, I'm wondering whether there is better design to handle such logon user case.
It seems Sharing-Nothing-Architecture helps. That means long user info is retrieved from database each time. I'm afraid that would hurt performance.

Is there any design pattern for long user web app?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Store session state in the database and put memcached in front of it.

Answer (score 1):

One method discussed on StackOverflow and elsewhere is the signed cookie. A cookie that has information you would otherwise not be able to trust, along with a hash created in such a way that only your server could have created it, so you know the information is valid. This is a scalable way to save non-high-security information, such as username. You don't have to access any shared resource to confirm that the user is logged in as long as the signed cookie meets all criteria (you should have a date stamp involved, to keep cookie theft from being a long term issue, and you should also keep track that the user has not authenticated, so they should have no access to more secure information without going through the usual login process).

[StackOverflow: Tips on signed cookies instead of sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523629/tips-on-signed-cookies-instead-of-sessions)