# Checking if user has changed cookie value, manually

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, session-cookies

I am busy with a login system for my project.

Just for an extra step to the security.. How can I check/detect if a user has manually changed a cookie value?

Is there some easy way of doing this? Or do I have to set an extra Session variable and match it up with that? With this being said, is a normal ASP.Net Session traceable by the browser? And viewable to the user?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could append a digital signature to the cookie value and check the signature when you read it back.  That way, if the cookie value is tampered with it will be very apparent.

```
private string sign(string hashStr, byte[] secret) 
{
    // Compute the signature hash
    HMACSHA1 mac = new HMACSHA1(secret);
    byte[] hashBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(hashStr);
    mac.TransformFinalBlock(hashBytes, 0, hashBytes.Length);
    byte[] hashData = mac.Hash;

    // Encode the hash in Base64.
    string hashOut = Convert.ToBase64String(hashData);

    return hashOut;
}
```

**Edit:** Fixed the encoder so it's explicitly UTF-8.

As usual, you should also be sure to add some salt to your string before calling this, see:   [Secure hash and salt for PHP passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401656/secure-hash-and-salt-for-php-passwords)

Comment: Thanks Bill, I will definitely use this.

Comment: What happens if someone copied the cookie from your PC and use it later ? how to prevent this

Comment: this code is for signing, where is the other part where we check for tampering?

Answer (score 2):

If you have to handle such sensitive information, I would suggest you not store it in user cookies. Instead use `sessions` to store such values as the user will not be able to tamper with such values.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you encrypt the cookie value. That way it is tough for the user to actually change it correctly. Like the previous answer mentions, if it is really sensitive, cookie is not the place to store it but encryption gives you a little bit more protection.

Comment: Encrypting isn't enough - you can change the values and it won't be detected (although decryption may fail, and of course the user is making blind changes) - you must also sign the cookie, as Bill Brasky suggests.

Comment: really brother, i don't think this answer deserves a downvote. check this answer out, it is an option. it depends on what your intentions are. May be encryption will work for his purpose. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/523629/tips-on-signed-cookies-instead-of-sessions

Answer (score 1):

Add a second variable to your cookie, which is unique to the first value.

On `Page_Load` compare the two values to the database.

If they do not match a record, then delete the cookie.