# Best way to make a constant HTML attribute value

Tags: javascript, html, dom, attributes, constants

I just want to get a value that I put in a HTML attribute like an id, and use it in my JavaScript code so I will be able to get that value with `this.id`.

The problem is that users can change this id with F12 and it will change the operation of my code.

So what is the best way to get data of a DOM Element and how to make it unchangable ?

Best regards.

Comment: You cannot trust anything on the client.

Comment: That is to say there is not any good solution ?

Comment: You need to redesign your system so that nothing that comes from the client matters.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to ensure that element attributes are constant.

If you want to ensure that the client does not tamper with data, you can use signed [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies). You would need to keep a signing key server side and use some library to set the cookie server side. For node and express, you can use [cookie-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-parser).

Nobody without knowledge of the signing key would be able to temper with signed data without the signature becoming invalid

Comment: Ok thank you, looks like I need to redesign my system though.

Comment: Yes. You will need a backend like node to use my method

Comment: Ok, is it possible to do that with PHP and Ajax for example ?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a standardised signed cookie format in php. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/523629/11168593) for some methods of doing signed cookies in php. As for ajax, check out the [fetch api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)