# How to check whether the Cookie is HttpOnly or not in PHP

Tags: php, cookies

I am using PHP to `set_cookie` with the HttpOnly secure flag to true. This all going well, but i want to know how can i check whether the cookie set is HttpOnly or not, when user come again to site.
If i will not be able to check it then user will make cookie from its side and then i will fetch cookie by `$_COOKIE["cookie"]` and the value will be there (user had set by Javascript or Devloper Tools).
I am doing it for logging in the user and remember it through leaving cookie. If there is any other way, then also suggest that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if httponly cookie exists in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9353630/check-if-httponly-cookie-exists-in-javascript)

Comment: @tajni no this not answer my question, I want to check if the cookie which is already set, is HttpOnly or Not in PHP

Comment: That flag is only intended to stop JavaScript from reading the cookie, it doesn't do anything else. On the client-side, when communicating with a server, the browser only sends cookie names and values. Everything else, including expires, secure, htp-only, domain, path, etc. are **not** sent to the server. If you are worried about cookie tampering, you can [sign cookies or switch to sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/523629/231316).

Comment: You must check then if cookie exists on client-side, and server-side and you will get answer comparing them.